# Magento 2: Make category field required in product form in backend

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.2.7

I want to make the **category field required** for **product form** in the **backend**.

I have tried to add the required class in the block class, but nothing happened.

Since the category field is not an input or dropdown field, I am not able to figure out how can I make it required.

[image: Make Category Field Required in Product Form in Backend]

Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to

```
Store -> Attributes -> Product.
```

Search for

```
category_ids
```

select

```
Yes
```

for

```
Values Required
```

it will work.

Tested and working.

[image]

Comment: Nice, thanks for the quick answer. I didn't expect such a simplest answer.